# Search in database if a value exists or not

Tags: php, database

I was trying to check the database for a specific value (id) so if its exist a message will be shown to users that the data exists ..
I came up with this lately but it doesn't work :

```
if (isset($_POST['id'])) 
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['id']));
} else {
    die("Try not to mess around bro!");
}

$query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM members WHERE id='$id'");
if (!$query) {
    die('Query failed to execute for some reason');
}
if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
    echo "this user already exists in the database!";
}
```

although a value exists in the database , no message are shown and am sure that the code is correct .. can anyone help me ? thanks in advance

Comment: You can try to print out the executed query and run it manually, and add a few more debug echo's. Otherwise it looks fine.

Comment: Consult [`my answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22731694/) @user3359695

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (isset($_POST['id'])) 
        $id = intval(mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['id'])));
    } else {
       die("Try not to mess around bro!");
    }

    echo "id=".$_POST['id'];
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM members WHERE id=$id");
    echo "rows="mysql_num_rows($query);

    if (!$query) {
        die('Query failed to execute for some reason');
    }
    if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
      echo "this user already exists in the database!";
    }
```

replace your code with above i made change in query(removed quote frome $id)

Comment: i edited in code replace again and tell me what value will print in as " id = " and  "rows ="

Answer (score 0):

change `echo "this user already exists in the database!";` to `die("this user already exists in the database!");`
it works very well for me

Answer (score 0):

It's because of this: (a missing opening brace). Therefore, your POST variable isn't being passed.

```
if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
//                       ^-- missing brace
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['id']));
} else {
    die("Try not to mess around bro!");
}
```

---

See comment `// <- to match this brace`

```
if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
//                       ^-- missing brace
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['id']));
} // <- to match this brace 
else {
    die("Try not to mess around bro!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//first you should enable error_Reporting to trace the bug in your code
error_reporting(E_ALL);
//second you should print mysql_error if query fail

//your code should be
$id = 0;//intail value for id so that no error happens if no POST sent
if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
$id = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['id']));
} else {
  die("Try not to mess around bro!");
}
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM members WHERE id='$id'"); 
if (!$query) {
   die(mysql_error());//to see the error in your query
   //die('Query failed to execute for some reason');
}
if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
  echo "this user already exists in the database!";
}
```